# DIfference between Intel Core and Haswell Intel Core

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i5, haswell

I want to buy a laptop and have found the one I want on two websites. It's exactly the same on both places, but one of them has an `Intel Core` CPU and the other is `Haswell Intel Core`. I started wondering what the difference might be.

After a little research I could mostly find reviews or comparisons between the i5 and i7, or this sort of thing, but not what `Haswell` actually means. Can anyone help?

Comment: Intel Core isn't a full product name we need more information to explain the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Intel's latest micro-architecture codename.

You can see more about what this means on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microarchitecture) but essentially, it's the successor to Ivy Bridge, and relates to their newest series of chips.

Comment: So, there is not much difference between the 2, and if I get the one with `Haswell` it's not a bad idea?

Comment: Haswell is the newest, and you'll benefit from performance and power consumption improvements at the cost of a higher price-tag.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Because the price of both machines is the same. :D

Answer (score 3):

Haswell was [the development codename](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_%28microarchitecture%29) for the newest iteration of the Intel Core architecture. Haswell-era Intel processors primary benefits to the end user are reduced power consumption and increased graphics performance.

If the one that's only described as "Intel Core" is [on this list](http://ark.intel.com/products/codename/42174/Haswell), it too is Haswell. If not, it's a generation or two behind the current generation.